# FFmpeg: Fade in and out from PNG generated video

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have a PNG image and want an 8 seconds 30 fps video from it with the first second faded in and the last one faded out. Here's what I expect to work, using the `fade` filter, but what produces just a black video of 8 s length instead, both using `2023-09-07-git-9c9f48e7f2-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev` and `4.2.1` back from 2019.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/8 -i t.png -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p ^
  -filter_complex "fade=in:0:30, fade=out:210:30" t.mp4
```

Without the filter (`-vf` or `-filter_complex`, no difference), an 8 sec video is created containing the PNG image as expected. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong in applying the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the command should be,

`ffmpeg -framerate 30 -loop 1 -t 8 -i t.png -vf "fade=in:0:30, fade=out:210:30" -pix_fmt yuv420p t.mp4`

1. The fade filter operates upon the frames supplied to it - it cannot generate new frames. Without input `-loop`, an image input is just a single frame stream.
2. Even with loop, a framerate of 1/8 will lead to the 2nd frame to have a timestamp of 8 seconds. The 240th frame will be at 1920 seconds. Not what you want.
3. Finally, limit looping to 8 seconds with `-t 8`.

Comment: Excellent, it works and makes sense. Thank you so much. • Here's a [link to a somewhat related filter & `-r` & `-framerate` question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51143100/269126) which you also answered with clarity. • What puzzled me was that without the filter, a 30 fps video of 8 s length was produced, hence I thought the filter was fed adequate input, but it wasn't. • Is there a reason why you moved `-pix_fmt yuv420p` to the end? • Unrelated: `ffmpeg -h` says `-h topic   show help`. But where can I find the list of known topics? I always get "Unknown help option '…'."

Comment: The pix_fmt is applied after the filtering, so shifted it there to reflect processing order.

Comment: There isn't a ToC for the CLI help. See the first two sections in the output of `ffmpeg -h`